# Java on MacOS sees external USB drive as not readable - all other applications see it as readable

Tags: java, macos, external, drive

Java (both 8 and 17) on Mac OSx (Macbook Pro M1, Monterey 12.3) sees an external USB drive as not readable. This used to work, believe that problem started with installation of 12.3. Test routine below shows both File(..).canRead() and Files.isReadable(..) returning false. All other applications (Finder, terminal, Time Machine) use the same drive with no issues. Problem report submitted to Apple, but has anyone else seen this issue?

NOTE: If the drive is not readable, then File(..).listFiles() returns NULL and Files.list(..) throws an exception.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

/** Test routine for failure to access external USB drive (USBExtA in testPath) from Java.
 *
 *  The testPath is attempting to access Time Machine backups on the external drive, which shows as not readable in Java.
 *  BUT IT IS READABLE with no problems from Finder, the terminal, and other applications. Time Machine is still
 *  successfully writing backups to this drive.
 *
 *  THIS USED TO WORK -- believe that it stopped working with installation of Monterey 12.3, and took a while
 *                       before I noticed the problem (but not exactly sure of the date when 12.3 installed).
 *
 *  ----------- Output of executions using Java 8 and Java 17 ------------------
 *
 * --------- Execution Context ----------
 *       java.version -- 1.8.0_311
 *        java.vendor -- Oracle Corporation
 *    java.vm.version -- 25.311-b11
 *     java.vm.vendor -- Oracle Corporation
 * java.class.version -- 52.0
 *            os.name -- Mac OS X
 *            os.arch -- x86_64
 *         os.version -- 10.16
 *
 * java.io.File -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T , java.nio.Files -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T  --- PATH: /Volumes
 * java.io.File -- Exists:  T , Readable: *F*, Dir:  T , java.nio.Files -- Exists:  T , Readable: *F*, Dir:  T  --- PATH: /Volumes/USBExtA
 *
 *  --------- Execution Context ----------
 *       java.version -- 17.0.1
 *        java.vendor -- Oracle Corporation
 *    java.vm.version -- 17.0.1+12-LTS-39
 *     java.vm.vendor -- Oracle Corporation
 * java.class.version -- 61.0
 *            os.name -- Mac OS X
 *            os.arch -- aarch64
 *         os.version -- 12.3
 *
 * java.io.File -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T , java.nio.Files -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T  --- PATH: /Volumes
 * java.io.File -- Exists:  T , Readable: *F*, Dir:  T , java.nio.Files -- Exists:  T , Readable: *F*, Dir:  T  --- PATH: /Volumes/USBExtA
 */
public class ExtUSBTest {

  public static String testPath = "/Volumes/USBExtA/Backups.backupdb/JDCMacBook";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    showContext("java.version", "java.vendor", "java.vm.version", "java.vm.vendor", "java.class.version",
                "os.name", "os.arch", "os.version");

    checkPath(Paths.get(testPath));
  }

  /** Recursively check all sub-components of the given path - stops if not exists && readable */
  public static boolean checkPath(Path path) {
    if(path.getParent() == null)
      return true;
    else if(checkPath(path.getParent()))
      return checkThisPath(path);
    else
      return false;
  }
  /** Check this particular path to see if exists & readable */
  public static boolean checkThisPath(Path path) {
    File f            = path.toFile();
    boolean fExists   = f.exists();
    boolean fReadable = f.canRead();
    boolean fDir      = f.isDirectory();
    boolean pExists   = Files.exists(path);
    boolean pReadable = Files.isReadable(path);
    boolean pDir      = Files.isDirectory(path);

    String rslt = String.format("java.io.File -- Exists: %s, Readable: %s, Dir: %s, java.nio.Files -- Exists: %s, Readable: %s, Dir: %s --- PATH: %s",
                                  bstr(fExists), bstr(fReadable), bstr(fDir), bstr(pExists), bstr(pReadable), bstr(pDir), path.toString());
    ln(rslt);
    return (fExists && fReadable) || (pExists && pReadable);
  }
  public static void showContext(String ... props) {
    ln("--------- Execution Context ----------");
    for(int i = 0; i<props.length; i++) showProp(props[i]);
    ln("");
  }
  public static void showProp(String property) {
    ln(String.format("%18s -- %s", property, System.getProperty(property)));
  }
  public static String bstr(boolean b) { return b ? " T " : "*F*";}

  public static void ln(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you need to grant permissions? Under System Preferences > Security & Privacy there is a Files and Folders section where you can manage this kind of permissions.

Comment: @gpunto - good suggestion. Added 'full disk access' to Java, but no change in results. Also added a key line to the original that File.listFiles(..) returns NULL and Files.list(path) throws an exception if directory is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following output when I ran the above code on my M1-Pro Mac running on Monterey 12.3. So, I don't think this is specific to the latest version of Monterey(12.3)!

```
    **--------- Execution Context ----------
      java.version -- 17.0.2
       java.vendor -- Amazon.com Inc.
   java.vm.version -- 17.0.2+8-LTS
    java.vm.vendor -- Amazon.com Inc.
java.class.version -- 61.0
           os.name -- Mac OS X
           os.arch -- aarch64
        os.version -- 12.3
java.io.File -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T , java.nio.Files -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T  --- PATH: /Volumes
java.io.File -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T , java.nio.Files -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T  --- PATH: /Volumes/SSD1
java.io.File -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T , java.nio.Files -- Exists:  T , Readable:  T , Dir:  T  --- PATH: /Volumes/SSD1/cp**
```

Comment: Interesting! So we have differences in the JVM, compiler, and the external device. Is your external device attached via USB, firewire, ethernet?? I've got a Sabrent USB drive caddy going through a Belkin dock. Suspected 12.3 because same device, compiler, JVM were working before. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not an answer - additional information - but needed more space. Wish that StackOverflow allowed attaching a file!!!

Wrote a self-contained test routine (pasted below). This **works** when

- Running under my own ID (an Admin)
- Running as a regular user
- Logged in (and running) as 'root'

Sample output:

```
Starting ....... at Sun Nov 13 17:24:15 EST 2022
        User: jdc
       Drive: /Volumes/USBExtA
      Exists: true
   isSymlink: false
 isDirectory: true
  isReadable: true          ----- NOTE
isExecutable: true

Level  1, Read  10 children, skipped   0, For: /Volumes/USBExtA
Level  2, Read   1 children, skipped   0, For: /Volumes/USBExtA/....
... rest omitted
```

It does **not** work when

- running under launchctl at the 'system' level
- running under launchctl at the 'user' level

Sample output:

```
Starting ....... at Sun Nov 13 16:34:02 EST 2022
        User: root              ---- running under 'root'
       Drive: /Volumes/USBExtA  ---- exactly the same mount
      Exists: true
   isSymlink: false
 isDirectory: true
  isReadable: false       ----- NOTE - now is not readable
isExecutable: true


.........Finished at Sun Nov 13 16:34:02 EST 2022
```

(Get the same output when running under 'jdc' via launchctl)

The full test code (Note: some symbols, such as less than, replaced with HTML entries such as &lt;):

```
    import java.nio.file.*;
    import java.util.Date;
    /** Test routine to access a mounted volume and attempt to read N levels of directories/files.
     *
     * Usage: java -jar [path/]JavaReadUSB.jar pathToMountedDrive N      -- where N is number of levels to read (may be 0)
     *
     * Example: java -jar /Users/myuser/tmp/JavaReadUSB.jar /Volumes/USBDrive 4
     *
     */
    public class ReadUSBMain {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        ln("");
        ln("Starting ....... at " + new Date().toString());
        if(args==null || args.length < 2)
          showUsage();
        else {
          String mount = args[0];
          int nTo      = getN(args);
    
          Path path = Paths.get(mount);
          if(pathOK(path)){
            processOneLevel(path, 1, nTo);
          }
        }
        ln("");
        ln(".........Finished at " + new Date().toString());
        ln("");
      }
    
      public static void processOneLevel(Path dir, int nLevel, int nTo){
        int skipped = 0;
        if(nLevel <= nTo) {
          try {
            Object[] arr = Files.list(dir).toArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
              Path p = (Path) arr[i];
              if(Files.isSymbolicLink(p) || (Files.isDirectory(p) && !Files.isReadable(p))) skipped++;
            }
            ln(String.format("Level %2d, Read %3d children, skipped %3d, For: %s", nLevel, arr.length, skipped, dir.toString()));
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
              Path p = (Path) arr[i];
              if(!Files.isSymbolicLink(p) && Files.isDirectory(p) && Files.isReadable(p)) processOneLevel(p, nLevel + 1, nTo);
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            err("Directory: " + dir.toString() + " Threw: " + e.toString());
          }
        }
      }
      public static boolean pathOK(Path path) {
        boolean exists       = Files.exists(path);
        boolean isSymLink    = Files.isSymbolicLink(path);
        boolean isDir        = exists && Files.isDirectory(path);
        boolean isReadable   = exists && Files.isReadable(path);
        boolean isExecutable = exists && Files.isExecutable(path);
    
        ln("        User: " + System.getProperty("user.name"));
        ln("       Drive: " + path.toString());
        ln("      Exists: " + exists);
        ln("   isSymlink: " + isSymLink);
        ln(" isDirectory: " + isDir);
        ln("  isReadable: " + isReadable);
        ln("isExecutable: " + isExecutable);
        ln("");
        return isDir && isReadable;
      }
      public static int getN(String[] args){
        return Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      }
      public static void showUsage(){
        ln("");
        ln("Usage: java -jar [path/]JavaReadUSB.jar pathToMountedDrive Nlevels");
        ln("");
        ln("Example: java -jar /Users/myuser/tmp/JavaReadUSB.jar /Volumes/USBDrive 4");
        ln("");
        ln("         N may be zero. Will show whether drive is readable, but not actually read anything.");
        ln("");
        ln("         Note: Any Symlink or directory which is not Readable is skipped and a count shown in the output");
        ln("");
      }
      public static void ln(String str) { System.out.println(str); }
      public static void err(String str){
        ln("");
        ln("ERROR -- " + str);
        ln("");
      }
    }
```